# No puedo tener conexión con MySQL

Tags: mysql

tengo el siguiente problema, agradecería si pueden ayudarme. 
Tengo instalado MySQL, instale lampp y al momento de ingresar a phpMyAdmin, me tira un error de conexión con MySQL, alguien me podría decir alguna forma de solucionarlo. Por favor. [image: Dejo una captura del error que me arroja.]

---

Se me olvidaba mencionar que utilizo Linux Mint 19.

Comment: Revisa los logs de error para ver el error a más detalle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trata de cambiar lo siguiente en el archivo **/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php**

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
```

cámbialo a:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
```